# Why is the amortized time for path compressions approximately $\mathcal{O}(1)$?

Tags: computer-science

For optimization of *Find* operations (an operation that returns the representative of the set a node belongs to) in a disjoint-set structure, path compression is used. Analysis of the operation approximately yields amortized complexity $\mathcal{O}\left(1\right)$.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) and a variety of other sources provide brief explanations - most identify the relation between path compression and the inverse Ackermann function, however do not provide a compendious description of the reasoning behind the relation.

**Why is the approximated amortized complexity of path compression in *Find* operations $\mathcal{O}\left(1\right)$?**

Comment: What does "*approximated* amortized complexity" mean? The amortized complexity of union-find with path compression is $O(\alpha(n))$, where $\alpha(n)$ is the inverse of the Ackermann function, and this is not $O(1)$. In any case, searching for "union find ackermann" on Google turns up a number of results, for example [these course notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS6820/2012sp/Handouts/48-57.pdf) by (I think) Dexter Kozen, which contain a proof.

Comment: @RahulNarain The inverse Ackermann function is an *extremely* slow growing function. For $n$ less than $2^{65536}$ (in other words all practical situations), $\mathcal{O}(\alpha(n))$ is equal to or less than $6$. Therefore for all realistic situations, $\mathcal{O}(\alpha(n))$ is *approximately* $\mathcal{O}(1)$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that  "...approximately yields amortized complexity $O(1)$" is a good statement. There is a very clear notation what [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) means when speaking about algorithms. It is better to phrase it as "... in the amortized running time per operation is effectively a small constant." as done in Wikipedia. This means that for all practical values the inverse Ackermann function $\alpha(n)$ can be bounded by a constant, since it grows very slow.

If you want to get an idea, why the $\alpha(n)$ shows up, I recommend the very readable [article](http://www-tcs.cs.uni-saarland.de/Papers/unionfind.ps.gz) by Seidel and Sharir. The paper shows first a $O(\log n)$ bound and then improves the bound to $O(\log^* n)$. However, the idea behind the improvement is still applicable to the $O(\log^* n)$ bound, and gives an even better bound. The repeated improvements culminate in the bound of $\alpha(n)$.